# Creating a new .HTML File and then uploading to Server or Database so others can view online

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, database

I'm working on a project where users can create a basic website with a homepage and 1 or 2 additional pages.

I can save the Content of the page to the database easily enough but need help on creating the new html file and then saving it either to a database or server so that others can then view it online once it's been loaded with the content saved to the database.

Originally I was thinking of having two tables linked together in a database, one that holds the pages and details of which elements each page will contain eg Nav, Header and Content.
The second table then hold the content for each element linked to its respective page.
Fields would be something like

```
Page Name       Nav                   Content
index.html      Some HTML/CSS Data    Some HTML/CSS Data
```

So basically I need some help creating the blank .html and either saving it to the database or a server so anyone can view the result, can then figure out how to populate them with data myself I think.

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know what you're choosing, is it dynamic(Storing pages in a database) or static(building standard html) pages you want to build.